# scala case class var val

Tags: scala, case, var

Can anyone explain this strange behavior with my case class?

```
case class  Dai(var g :Int) {
  def getG() = g
}

val dai: Dai = Dai(20)

dai.g = 30
// why v2 difference with getGet
val v2 = dai.getG  // 30
var getGet = dai.getG // 20
```

Comment: can you copy full code that can run?

Comment: Are you running this code in an Intellij worksheet? I can reproduce the problem in Intellij (with Scala 2.11.4) but not in the REPL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellij Worksheet has this problem
[image: Intellij Worksheet]

But not from the REPL
[image: REPL]

Must have something to do with how Intellij is running the worksheet?

Comment: yes,I am run in the intellij. not in the repl.,I have test in normal class ,it's ok.thanks

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't happen on my system running 2.11.2. Most probably a bug that can be fixed by upgrading your distribution.

```
scala> case class  Dai(var g :Int) {
     |   def getG() = g
     | }
defined class Dai

scala> 

scala> val dai: Dai = Dai(20)
dai: Dai = Dai(20)

scala> 

scala> dai.g = 30
dai.g: Int = 30

scala> // why v2 difference with getGet

scala> val v2 = dai.getG  // 30
v2: Int = 30

scala> var getGet = dai.getG // 20
getGet: Int = 30
```